# Serverless lambda with websocket doesn't save the received data

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, serverless

I'm trying to access one of my node.js lambda functions from an HTML form, using Javascript, but the lambda doesn't save the data.

Here is the Javascript from the HTML page:

```
                let user = document.getElementById('userLogged');
                let currentUser = user.textContent;
                let channel = document.getElementById('channelLogged');
                let currentChannel = channel.textContent;
                let message = $("#messageText").val();
                let socket = new WebSocket(WEBS + currentChannel);

                socket.onopen = () => {
                    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
                        action: "sendMessage",
                        data: {
                            messageText: message,
                            username: currentUser,
                            currentChannel: currentChannel
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
```

And here are my lamba function, that is supposed to send and save the messages:

```
module.exports.sendMessageHandler = (event, context, callback) => {
    sendMessageToAllConnected(event).then(() => {
        callback(null, successfullResponse)
    }).catch (err => {
        callback(null, JSON.stringify(err));
    });
};

const sendMessageToAllConnected = (event) => {
    const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
    const message = body.data.messageText;
    const channel = body.data.currentChannel;
    const user = body.data.username;
  return getConnectionIds(channel).then(connectionData => {
    return connectionData.Items.map(connectionId => {
      return saveMessages.save(event, user, channel, message, connectionId.connectionId);
    });
  });
};

const getConnectionIds = channel => {
    const params = {
        TableName: CHATCONNECTION_TABLE,
        Key: {
            channel: channel
        },
        ProjectionExpression: 'connectionId'
    };
    return dynamo.scan(params).promise();
};


module.exports.getMessagesHandler = event => {
    const channel = event.queryStringParameters.channel;
    const params = {
        TableName: MESSAGE_TABLE,
        Key: {
          channel: channel
          },
        ProjectionExpression: 'username, messageDate, messageText'
    };
   return dynamo.scan(params).promise();
};

module.exports.save = (event, user, channel, message, connectionId) => {

    const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
    const postData = body.data;

    const endpoint = event.requestContext.domainName + "/" + event.requestContext.stage;
    const apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
        apiVersion: "2018-11-29",
        endpoint: endpoint
    });

    const postParams = {
        connectionId : connectionId,
        Data: postData
    };

    const dbParams = {
        TableName: MESSAGE_TABLE,
        Item: {
            channel: channel,
            messageDate: Date.now(),
            username: user,
            messageText: message,
        }
    };
    dynamo.put(dbParams);

   return apigwManagementApi.postToConnection(postParams).promise();
};
```

The sls logs for the sendMessageHandler don't return any error, but I don't see there any result from the request. Also, I have another lambda, that is supposed go get all the saved messages, but returns error that channel key is undefined.

```
module.exports.getMessagesHandler = event => {
    const channel = event.queryStringParameters.channel;
    const params = {
        TableName: MESSAGE_TABLE,
        Key: {
          channel: channel
          },
        ProjectionExpression: 'username, messageDate, messageText'
    };
   return dynamo.scan(params).promise();
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Lambda isn't running 24/7, in the sense that your socket wont open until the Lambda function is invoked. Are you getting any indication that its actually running at all ?

Comment: When I run sls logs -f sendMessageHandler in the terminal, it returns no error, but the return doesn't has the input data I sent also. It has something like Request Id started: and Request Id ended:

Answer (score 0):

I resolved one of the problems- changed the `const channel = event.queryStringParameters.channel;` to `const channel = event.query.channel;` and now I don't get the error that `channel` is undefined. But now I have a problem with appending the result of `getMessagesHandler` to the HTML. Here is the code for that.

```
                debugger;
                let user = $("#username").val();
                let channel = $("#channel").val();
                const URL = 'https://ktwdb7v696.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/getMessages?channel=';
                let realURL = URL + channel;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: realURL,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#loginForm").css("visibility", "hidden");
                        $("#messageForm").css("visibility", "visible");
                        $("#messages").css("visibility", "visible");
                        // $("#userLogged").text(user);
                        // $("#channelLogged").text(channel);
                        document.getElementById('userLogged').innerHTML = user;
                        document.getElementById('channelLogged').innerHTML = channel;
                        document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = 'Please write a message to send';
                        data.Items.forEach(function (message) {
                            console.log(message.messageDate);
                            console.log(message.username);
                            console.log(message.messageText);
                            $('#messages').append('<p>Date: ' + message.messageDate + '</p>'
                                    + '<p>User: ' + message.username + '</p>'
                                    + '<p>Message: ' + message.messageText + '</p>'
                            );
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

In fact I think there is nothing to append at all, anyone can help with that?